# How to make a bootable command prompt usb?

Tags: command-line, boot

There are many ways to make bootable Windows USB pen drive, but I would like to make a bootable windows command prompt from an USB pen drive.

Is there a way using diskpart or another program? If not, is there a way to make a bootable Linux terminal via USB?

Comment: What is a "bootable windows command prompt"?

Comment: Command line on system startup, like a boot CD/DVD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Current best method:**

Since some year, practically all of the distributions have a bootable ISO image. It results, you can simply write out the ISO to the USB device, and it will boot:

```
dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdd
```

Of course **double-check** if you gave to correct block device.

---

**Old method, only for Windows client machines:**

Download the iso image of your most beloved linux distribution (if there isn't any, I suggest you ubuntu). They are freely downloadable from their homepage.

Download the tool named unetbootin for windows.

This unetbootin can write an iso image to an usb pendrive.

After you booted ubuntu from the pendrive, you can freely call a terminal program, or with ctrl/alt/f2 can you switch to command line console mode.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to access the Windows Command Prompt (CMD) quickly and easily - you'd want to get your hands on a windows 7 iso.  Then, using a program called Rufus:  https://rufus.akeo.ie/  create a bootable flash drive.  Then by selecting "One Time Boot Options/Selection" (typically by pressing "Esc", "F2", "F9", "F10", or "F12" at startup) and selecting the "USB" or "{Name of your flashdrive}" or entering BIOS Settings (pressing "Esc", "F2" or "F12  at startup) and setting the boot order to boot to flash drive 1st* and boot up the newly created image on the flash drive.

*Note:  For Windows 8/8.1/10 users you need to enter "BIOS Security Settings" and DISABLE Security Boot and ENABLE Legacy Boot (select "Yes" to continue if it gives you a prompt about changing system settings, I assure you it's fine).

When the Windows All In One loads to the very first Blue Screen hold SHIFT+F10*, simultaneously, and the command prompt will appear.  This is an ELEVATED Command Prompt which makes you all powerful.

*Note:  For Windows 8/8.1/10 users you may need to hold SHIFT+Fn+F10 simultaneously.  Furthermore, if you can't get Windows 8/8.1/10 to load the Command Prompt by Pressing the aforementioned keys, just select the "Repair Your Computer" link in the Windows Install interface and then select "Troubleshoot" and then "Command Prompt".

P.S. The Windows 8/8.1 Install .iso media works the same way.  ...load up the first Blue Screen and press either SHIFT+F10 or SHIFT+Fn+F10.

Good Luck and Cheers.

About the Author:

I made this post because I had to search for HOURS and through a plethora of Forums just to find this method.  For some reason the searches will redirect you to everything but, depending on how you word your respective search (thanks google) and it is infuriating.  I hope this post finds you well.  FBGM

Comment: That's a fairly sketchy download for the ISO. I would recommend using an actual Windows installation disc as the source.

Comment: Quite a few folks would consider downloading an all in one disk from an unknown sources piracy (and somewhat dangerous). If you do have a valid key, you can download windows 7 8 or 10 media directly from microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Download [MS WAIK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753) and [create a WinPE boot USB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744530%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: It seems the good win version of the solution, ++

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something bootable to make partition changes and repairs, check out:

http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

It includes a USB creation tool, if that does not work, check out:

http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-dos-from-usb/:

> **Boot DOS from USB**
>
> Creating a DOS Bootable USB Flash drive to "Boot DOS from USB", is not
>   very complicated. However, a tool called Rufus, created by Pete
>   Batard, can make this task simple. Rufus can also be used to create a
>   Bootable USB version of a given distro from an ISO File. Rufus is
>   similar in appearance and operation to the HP USB Format tool
>   "HPUSBFW.exe", and shares many of the same features. However, Rufus is
>   Open Source.
>
> **Booting DOS from USB**
>
> How to Create a DOS Bootable USB Flash Drive that can ultimately be
>   used to Run DOS from USB, using Rufus.
>
> **Authors Website:** http://rufus.akeo.ie/
>
> 1. Download Rufus and launch the program
> 2. (1) Select your USB **Device** from the drop down, (2) Choose the **Fat32** filesystem, (3) Tick the option to **Create a DOS bootable disk**
> 3. Click the **Start** button to create the DOS Bootable Drive
> 4. Restart your PC, setting your BIOS to boot from the USB device, boot and enjoy!